# How to execute jQuery callback before data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

I have a simple post, which executed the data returned as a script as such:

```
$.post("/home", { foo: 'bar' }, function(){
    //callback function
}, "script");
```

Here's what happens:

1. The request gets sent
2. A piece of JS code is returned as a
   response and executed
3. The callback is executed

I need the callback to be executed **before** the returned JS is executed.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change how jQuery handle the request. After all, a callback is a callback and it gets executed once the job is done! You can, however, set the `dataType` to `"text"` and then eval your Javascript.

Ex:

```
$.post("/home", { foo: 'bar' }, function(data){
   //callback function

   // execute JS
   $.globalEval( data );
}, "text");
```

** **UPDATE** **

This is what jQuery does internally (snipped) :

```
// If the type is "script", eval it in global context
} else if ( type === "script" || !type && ct.indexOf("javascript") >= 0 ) {
   jQuery.globalEval( data );
}
```

So, there is no security risk with taking the `globalEval` out of the Ajax request and executing it in the callback function.

Comment: this seems ideal. does jquery execute the script in the same way? (i.e. call `eval()`)? If not, are there any security flaws in doing that?

Comment: This is what JQuery does internally if you set dataType as "script", so no. If there is no risk one way, there is no risk another. :) Read the update for the answer.

Comment: I looked at the jQuery source code and that's not how it does it at all - it created a script tag, handles the script loading, various IE memory leaks, and then appends the script tag to the head element. I think I'll just find a workaround - `eval` doesn't seem to do the same job. thanks anyways!

Comment: it creates a <script> tag only if the requested URL is using GET and if the dataType is "script". This is not your case here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.ajax()` and build your own script tag.

```
$.ajax({url:"/home",
        data: { foo: 'bar' },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'text',     // Return dataType is "text" instead of "script"
        success: function( script ){
           // run your code
           alert('mycode');
           // then create your own script tag
           var tag = document.createElement('script');
           tag.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
           tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(script));
           document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(tag);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use "BeforeSend" option that is executed before send the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",

    url: "SOMEURL",

    data: { "WHATEVER": whatever },

    beforeSend: function() {

      //DO WHATEVER BEFORE SEND AJAX CALL

    }
.....

});
```

}

Hope this helps.

best regards.

Jose

Comment: I need it execute after the request is sent and before the script is executed. `beforeSend` gets executed before the request is sent. thanks though!

Comment: Helo Yuval,

maybe this ajax event could help you ".ajaxStop event" check this page: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/. Im not sure if the code into ajaxStop will be executed before your js returned by ajax call. But maybe could work.

You could check .ajaxSucess too here: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score -2):

This $.post() function does not automatically execute the JS which is returned. It is probably executed in the callback function.

Comment: it does, if you specify `script` as the fourth parameter, which I did.

Comment: well then, i think you just answered your own question ;)